# Problem installing PostgreSQL version 12.4 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I am facing an issue when I am trying to install PostgreSQL on Windows 10. I have downloaded the application (v12.4) from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads but when I try to invoke the graphical installer, **the installation wizard does not appear** even after I have assumed administrator privileges (Using "Run as administrator").

I have also tried changing the compatibility and disabling firewall but nothing is working. The log of the installer is as shown but I can't figure out what is wrong.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try starting `cmd.exe` as administrator and launch it from there.

Comment: Tried it, but the installation wizard/setup wizard still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the installer, just right click on that and select run as administrator. That should launch the installer in GUI mode.

EDIT: We are able to resolve the issue after uninstalling the anti-virus.

Comment: Tried this, but the installer is still not launched in GUI mode which is weird because all other applications still can be installed.

Comment: Try logging on system with an administrator user and give it a try.

Comment: I'm using my own laptop so I am using the administrator account, so I have no idea why it's not installing.

Comment: Btw, I'm using a x64 based PC and I can install other x64 programs normally, except for PostgreSQL v12.4-windowsx64, which is why it is weird that the graphical installer is not invoked when I run the application, even as administrator.

Comment: will you please check if there is an ERROR word in the install log.

Comment: Nope, there is no install log (I think this means it's not being installed?), however I there is a installbuilder_installer file which does not show any error. When I run task manager as I run the installation, I see a postgresql installation background process running but nothing shows up still.

Comment: The image that you post is the install log. but this is not the complete one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220413/discussion-between-chew-kah-meng-and-amjad-shahzad).